# Why is a 'undefined' in this code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, variable-declaration, hoisting

```js
var a = 10;

function Obj() {
  console.log(a);
  let a = 10;
}

Obj()
```

on calling function Obj value of a is printed as undefined

Comment: I would think that would return an error, not undefined

Comment: Look into closure and hoisting in JS https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: If you used `var` and not let it would be `undefined` and there are plenty of questions on stackoverflow that talk about hoisting.

Comment: `function Obj() { let a = 10;
  console.log(a); 
}` try this code

Answer (score 1):

Your mistakes are:

1: you don't need a function to log a message into the  console, you can call it directly and if will log it out.
example:

```
  Let a = 10 
  console.log(a)
```

The result will be 10

2: when you initialise a global variable and also initialise a function, calling both of them at the same time will throw error or multiple render.
example:

```
  Let a = 10;
  function Obj() {
    console.log(a)
    let a = 10;
  }

Obj() // this and the global will intend to run once, which will cause error.
```

Best practice is to call your function as a callback, so it will log when event is trigger
Example:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", obj)
```

when this button is clicked it will log 10

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses scope chains to establish the scope for a given function. There is typically one global scope, and each function defined has its own nested scope. Any function defined within another function has a local scope which is linked to the outer function. It's always the position in the source that defines the scope.

An element in the scope chain is basically a Map with a pointer to its parent scope.

When resolving a variable, javascript starts at the innermost scope and searches outwards.

Your example runs if you write it so:

```
console.log(this.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing let and const values before they are declared can cause a ReferenceError because of temporal dead zone

Answer (score 0):

a is not undefined. The function returns undefined since you have not specified what it should return. It actually returns an error but if it were to run you would see that undefined.

Code all together gives you:

Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Its due to scopes, in local, function scope, a is later defined with let which override the definition before function.

You can try two things:

- If you try `console.log(window.a)` you will get the correct value (outer a, the one defined outside of function scope).
- If you move `let a = 10;` to the start of the function block you will get that value.

Answer (score 0):

When u invoke the `Obj()` function. JavaScript engine will read this like below-

```
function Obj() { 
    let a;  //variable hoisting

    console.log(a); 

    a = 10;     
}
```

So without variable initialization variable a value will be undefined.

Comment: no it does not, that is not how `let` works. That would be the case for `var` Run the code above, you will see the error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that variables declared with `let` have block scope. And you can not declare same variable again within same scope, It will give error.
So in your case you're declaring `a` at the end of your function. So it's not declared yet.

Instead of using `var` to declare variable it will not throw such error but will return `undefined`.

For better understanding concepts about `let` you can go through following link.

1. [let variable](https://javascript.info/variables)
2. [var variable](https://javascript.info/var)

Answer (score 0):

Here in your case the code is breaking on first console. As the scope of `a` is within the function and you haven't defined it before printing.

I have made some examples to show you different scenarios of initialisation.

```js
const derp = 10

const blerg = (derp) => {
 console.log('Checking case1: ', derp)
 //Reason: Here derp is the prop passed to the function and passed undefined to it.
}

const blerg2 = (derp) => {
 console.log('Checking case2: ', derp)
 //Reason: Here derp is the prop passed to the function
}

const blerg3 = () => {
 console.log('Checking case3: ', derp)
 // Throws Error
 //Reason: Here derp scope is within the function and not defined so far.
let derp = 20
console.log('Checking case4: ', derp)
// This line won't print because already code broke on the above console.
}

blerg()
blerg2(derp) // Passing the derp initialised on line 1
blerg3() // Passing nothing to the function
```

Answer (score -1):

Functions without any return value, return `undefined` by default.

Your `Obj`function will run and output the console log but it will return undefined. Meaning "the return value of the function is not defined".

Check this if you are new to JS :) https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_mistakes.asp

Comment: but that function is not going to return anything in its current state

Comment: Exactly the return value is undefined. I dont get what you are trying to achieve. You are just running a function. Not even assigning the return to a value.

Comment: I am not the OP.... The function will not return because it throws an error. That is what I was inferring.

Comment: This answer isn't accurate; the OP's code *doesn't* run and throws a reference error.

Comment: The code doesn't even *try* to print the return value of the function so what it returns is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

```js
var a = 10;

function Obj() {
  console.log(a);
  let a = 10;
}

Obj()
```

Function is also an object and to its properties, 1st the a:undefined the you perform a read of undefined(read about hoisting in javascript!).